# Render Text on Image, Save Image in full resolution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uikit

I need to add a text label to an image, then give the user the ability to save the image with the text on it. The problem is, I can't find any good information on how to do this. Signs point to using UIKit's `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`. I'm not even sure if this is the right direction to be looking in. I need the images to not be scaled down when they're saved. They have to retain their resolution.

I'm at a loss. Any advice or help as to where to look or what to try next would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that will create a `UIImage` from a view (including it's subviews). Assuming the image is in a `UIImageView`, add the users text in a `UILabel` as a subview of the `UIImageView`.

```
+(UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view{

    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

    CGSize imageSize = view.bounds.size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Currently it uses the size of view as the size of the image. If you want it to be a different size, then you could pass in the desired size of the resulting image and set `imageSize` as appropriate.

You will need to add the QuartzCore foundation to your project and add
`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your .m file.

Here is the applicable code in a `UIViewController` to size the resulting image to that of the source image, most of which is in the `saveButtonTapped` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animal"];
    self.onScreenImageView.image = sourceImage;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"Source image size: %0.0f x %0.0f", sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height);
    NSLog(@"onScreenImageView size: %0.0f x %0.0f", self.onScreenImageView.frame.size.width, self.onScreenImageView.frame.size.height);
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *offScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sourceImage];
    NSLog(@"offScreenImageView size: %0.0f x %0.0f", offScreenImageView.frame.size.width, offScreenImageView.frame.size.height);

    UILabel *offScreenLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 1000, 100)];
    offScreenLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:80.f];
    offScreenLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    offScreenLabel.text = @"User Image Label Text";
    [offScreenImageView addSubview:offScreenLabel];

    UIImage *labeledImage = [NAHLabelPictureVC imageFromView:offScreenImageView];
    NSLog(@"Labeled image size: %0.0f x %0.0f", labeledImage.size.width, labeledImage.size.height);
    self.labeledImageView.image = labeledImage;
}
```

And the output from the `NSLog`s:

```
2013-06-28 15:57:13.052 SOSandbox[28772:907] Source image size: 1213 x 1159
2013-06-28 15:57:13.055 SOSandbox[28772:907] onScreenImageView size: 200 x 200
2013-06-28 15:57:14.963 SOSandbox[28772:907] offScreenImageView size: 1213 x 1159
2013-06-28 15:57:14.992 SOSandbox[28772:907] Labeled image size: 1213 x 1159
```

Comment: I was reading this in Apple's documentation earlier before I asked this question. How would I create an image that's the actual size of the image captured from the camera? That's what's confusing me, because this would end up creating something pretty small on a phone, no?

Comment: Or am I misinterpreting how this method handles the data/image capturing?

Comment: The view you pass in does not need to be on the screen of the device, thus you can create, for example, a `UIImageView` with its size being the same of the source image. Then add your `UILabel` as a subview. Do this 'off screen' after the user indicates the labeled image should be saved.

Comment: Depending on the requirement, you may need to increase the size of `UILabel` font and calculate its frame based on the size of the original image.

Comment: Hmm. Do you know anywhere I could find sample code for this? I looked for hours and couldn't find much of anything on this topic.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a method that creates a 'labeled' image that is the same size as the source image.

Comment: You rock Bob. My only regret is that I've got but one reputation to give!